# Start Airflow dag automatically once it is available in dagbag

Tags: airflow

Is there anyway to start the dag automatically without manually triggering dag once it is available in dagbag, considering *is_paused_upon_creation=false* is set.

Comment: you can schedule your DAG to run at particular point of time, like every monday at 10AM or 1st of every month, you can read more about this at https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.1/scheduler.html#:~:text=The%20Airflow%20scheduler%20monitors%20all,whether%20they%20can%20be%20triggered.

Comment: Yes we can schedule at particular point of time..but I want to run it whenever dag gets created.

Comment: @arya.s can you please check and evaluate my answer?

Answer (score 2):

Please, try to create your DAG with `schedule_interval='@once'`. It should works.